# Are sock puppet comment and Meta votes retracted?

Tags: support, comments, voting, moderator-tools, sock-puppets

A user used sock puppets to self-upvote, self-bounty, and self-accept answers they'd ask questions on. It is unknown whether this included voting on Meta posts or on comments.

Only one sock was deleted, others were suspended and their votes and accepts on main site retracted. Moreover, after rep reversal and suspension, a sock puppet has since voted on Meta.

Is such voting tracked? If so, are they retracted - in case of a deleted and non-deleted sock -  and when?

Comment: Meta votes most definitely are removed if the profile is deleted, it's the comment votes I'm less certain about. I'm not looking at the code, as far as I'm aware even comment votes have to be tied to a profile on a site so if the profile goes away, the votes do, too. There's likely some caching involved as we may not recalc things immediately but I would expect such votes to be removed, yes. For posts, if you think the score hasn't been recalculated, you can view the vote split and it will recalculate.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, though - socks are generally deleted but your question seems to imply that didn't happen. As such, it's unclear to me what you're specifically trying to understand. CMs will manually invalidate votes in some cases - or sometimes merge accounts instead of deleting but the former generally happens when we determine there's improper votes but there's still a chance the accounts belong to two users and the latter happens only when CMs investigate. Since you can't vote for yourself, these votes would be reassigned to the main account and de-duplicated.

Comment: Only one of the several socks were removed. The rest were suspended and their votes and accepts on main site retracted. Since a CM is involved in rep reversal, they can answer your query. My question is what happens to both, deleted and non-deleted, former of which seems answered.

Comment: If you update the question to be a bit more clear, I can try to provide more details... though it'll be general. :) If this is about a specific case, I'd recommend talking with the site mods about it or reaching out to us through the Contact form. (You know I'm a CM, right?) We can only give so much specific information out but there's likely some general process we can explain here.